# Convert ISO2 country code

Tags: grails, converters, iso, country

My goal is to concert a code like 'CH' in Switzerland , I want to convert it in the language of the locale of the users browser

I tried to use the country tag provided by grails:

```
<g:country code="che"/>
```

But it seems working only with IOS3 codes.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.util.Locale` instance yourself

```
def l = new Locale('de', 'CH')
l.displayCountry // will display `Switzerland` on a computer with English locale
l.getDisplayCountry(l)  // will display `Schweiz`
l.getDisplayCountry(request.locale) // the answer to your question
```